# Postfix : Relay Access Denied due to ESMTP

Tags: postfix, smtp, mailman

I have setup mailman and postfix, but the mails are not sent to through the mailing list. Postfix rejects it because the recipient domain is not added in `postfix_domains`.

This is my `main.cf`:

```
recipient_delimiter = +
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 500
owner_request_special = no
myhostname = develop.product.company.com
mynetworks = 10.92.5.5/16

# Increase deferred mail delivery frequency
queue_run_delay = 60s
minimal_backoff_time = 30s
maximal_backoff_time = 120s
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
recipient_delimiter = +
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 500
owner_request_special = no
transport_maps =  hash://opt/mailman/var/data/postfix_lmtp
local_recipient_maps =  hash://opt/mailman/var/data/postfix_lmtp
relay_domains = hash://opt/mailman/var/data/postfix_domains
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

The mailing lists in Mailman have been created in `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`, the file `postfix_domains` looks like:

```
# AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY MAILMAN ON 2017-02-09 02:43:51
#
# This file is generated by Mailman, and is kept in sync with the binary hash
# file.  YOU SHOULD NOT MANUALLY EDIT THIS FILE unless you know what you're
# doing, and can keep the two files properly in sync.  If you screw it up,
# you're on your own.

domain1.com domain1.com
domain2.com domain2.com
```

When I try sending a mail to that mailing list, in which `persona@company.com` is a subscriber, I get the following error:

```
postfix/smtpd[8110]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 454 4.7.1 <persona@company.com>: Relay access denied; from=<testing-mailinglist-bounces@domain1.com> to=<persona@company.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<ip-10-92-34-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal>
```

I run the following command `postconf -d | grep "smtpd_r"` to get the following results :

```
postscreen_reject_footer = $smtpd_reject_footer
smtpd_recipient_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_overshoot_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
smtpd_reject_footer =
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_restriction_classes =
```

I have read similar questions asked in this forum, but I do not find such an exact problem. Can anybody help me out with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorized networks are defined with the *mynetworks* configuration parameter in *main.cf*

As you are sending email from localhost:

```
postfix/smtpd[8110]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 454 4.7.1 <persona@company.com>: Relay access denied; from=<testing-mailinglist-bounces@domain1.com> to=<persona@company.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<ip-10-92-34-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal>
```

You have to allow postfix to forward email coming from localhost. Edit *main.cf* adding:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
```